# Multiple Queries using name as a link

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that pulls sales information for employees.

An example of the query would be:

```
Select Name, Customer_count, item1, item2, item3
from Invoices
```

Output:

```
Name    Customer_Count   item1   item2   item3
Rob         10             1       2       0
Bill        10             3       0       2
Jim         10             2       1       3
```

I have a second query that pulls the percentage of each item.

```
Select 
     Name, 
     Customer_count, 
     Cast(Cast(item1 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item1 , 
     Cast(Cast(item2 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item2, 
     Cast(Cast(item3 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item3
from Invoices


Name    Customer_Count   item1   item2   item3
Rob         10           10.00    20.00    0.00
Bill        10           30.00    0.00     20.00
Jim         10           20.00    10.00    30.00
```

How could I have the following output, Query 1 listed, with the name, query 2 below it, not listing the name.:

```
Name    Customer_Count   item1   item2   item3
Rob         10             1        2       0
            10            10.00    20.00    0.00
Bill        10             3        0       2
            10             30       0.00    20.00
Jim         10             2        1       3
            10             20       10.00   30.00
```

Comment: This is something you should rather do within your presentation layer. Anyway it is possible. But there is column with a 1:1 relation missing and some column to order by...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `UNION ALL` clause and do the union of the two queries, and then use the result in the `FROM` sentence. For ordering the rows the way you want, you can simply add the primary key column (or columns) to each `SELECT` sentence and add a column that will contain the visible name. This `Visible_name` column will contain the `Name` value for the first select of the union, and in the second select will contain an empty string.

The `ORDER BY` clause must order first by the primary key column(s) and second by the `Visible_name` column in descending order.

Supposing that `Invoices` table has an `Id` column as a primary key, the query can be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM

(Select Id, Name, Name AS Visible_name, Customer_count, item1, item2, item3
from Invoices

UNION ALL

Select
     Id,
     Name,
     '' AS Visible_Name, 
     Customer_count, 
     Cast(Cast(item1 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item1 , 
     Cast(Cast(item2 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item2, 
     Cast(Cast(item3 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item3
from Invoices
)

ORDER BY Id, Visible_name DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

This will get you pretty close.

```
select name, customer_count, item1, item2, item3
from 
(
    select 
    rownum = row_number() over (order by name),
    name, customer_count, item1, item2, item3
    from Invoices

    union 

    Select rownum = row_number() over (order by name), 
    '', Customer_count, 
    Cast(Cast(item1 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) * 100 as item1 , 
    Cast(Cast(item2 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) * 100 as item2, 
    Cast(Cast(item3 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) * 100 as item3
    from Invoices
) x
order by rownum, name desc
```

Note the item[n] values all have decimals. I am not sure how to get it to look like your example, but maybe that doesn't matter that much.

Noel

Answer (score 2):

You might use a mixture of two sets. Create both sets with a running number in jumps of 2 (2,4,6,8,...) and add a 1 to the second set (3,5,7,9,...).

If you sort it after this you will "mix" both sets

I use the name field to sort after- which is - for sure a bad idea...

And - if you want the Items without decimals be displayed as "1" instead of "1.00", you'll have to do extra output formatting...

EDIT: I just replaced the "Name" in the second set with an empty space...

```
DECLARE @dummyTbl TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),Customer_count INT, item1 INT ,item2 INT,item3 INT);
INSERT INTO @dummyTbl VALUES
 ('Rob',10,1,2,0)
,('Bill',10,3,0,2)
,('Jim',10,2,1,3);

SELECT *
FROM
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) * 2 AS Nr
          ,Name, Customer_count, item1, item2, item3
    from @dummyTbl

    UNION ALL

    Select 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) * 2 + 1 AS Nr,
         '', 
         Customer_count, 
         Cast(Cast(item1 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item1 , 
         Cast(Cast(item2 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item2, 
         Cast(Cast(item3 as float) / Cast(Customer_Count as float) as decimal (10,2)) as item3
    from @dummyTbl
) AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.Nr
```

The result

```
Nr  Name    Customer_count  item1   item2   item3
2   Bill    10              3.00    0.00    2.00
3           10              0.30    0.00    0.20
4   Jim     10              2.00    1.00    3.00
5           10              0.20    0.10    0.30
6   Rob     10              1.00    2.00    0.00
7           10              0.10    0.20    0.00
```

Comment: When you say "Output" formatting, what exactly do you mean?  I tried casting in the the first (item1), (item2) etc but the total sold, still comes over as a decimal.

Comment: @Shmewnix Try something like `CAST(CAST(item1 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10))` for the first and the same, but without the `CAST as INT` for the second...